# Android: Hiding my app service from displaying on the running programs

Tags: android, service

On Android,how to hide my application service from displaying on the list of running programs? As far as I know, system services are not displayed on the list and I wonder I can achieve the same behavior for my application.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do that while system service can.

Because your application is a guest while system services are hosts.

They hide the system services on purpose.

And show your application on purpose too.

This is the rule of the game.

If you are wondering why the running list in settings-applications page is different from the list you are programmatically getting via AM.getRunningServices(), you might need to spend some time to look at the source code in the settings app. Here is a snap shot of the code of src/com/android/settings/applications/RunningState.java in packages/apps/Settings.

```
 856         // Retrieve list of services, filtering out anything that definitely
 857         // won't be shown in the UI.
 858         List<ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo> services
 859                 = am.getRunningServices(MAX_SERVICES);
 860         int NS = services != null ? services.size() : 0;
 861         for (int i=0; i<NS; i++) {
 862             ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo si = services.get(i);
 863             // We are not interested in services that have not been started
 864             // and don't have a known client, because
 865             // there is nothing the user can do about them.
 866             if (!si.started && si.clientLabel == 0) {
 867                 services.remove(i);
 868                 i--;
 869                 NS--;
 870                 continue;
 871             }
 872             // We likewise don't care about services running in a
 873             // persistent process like the system or phone.
 874             if ((si.flags&ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo.FLAG_PERSISTENT_PROCESS)
 875                     != 0) {
 876                 services.remove(i);
 877                 i--;
 878                 NS--;
 879                 continue;
 880             }
 881         }
```

Comment: While my application is a built-in system applications. I have system privileges.

Comment: If you are building your own firmware image, please modify the source code of activity manager service to implement this special requirement.

Comment: We are helping  manufacturers to built-in applications , but not buiding our own image.So I hope that in the application layer to implement this special requirement.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. You can see many build in Google services and other non-system services like media process / exchange process etc. are also displayed in the running process list. Yours is no different from them.

Comment: When I use the code to get the list of running services,I found that use the code to get the sizes more than click Settings in the mobile terminal applications then running services sizes in the list of services. This proves that many applications service does not appear in the list of services running.

Comment: I use the code: ActivityManager manager =(ActivityManager) getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
  List<RunningServiceInfo> infos =manager.getRunningServices(100);
  for (RunningServiceInfo info:infos) {
   LogUtil.LogE(TAG, "service name="+info.service.getClassName());
  }
  LogUtil.LogE(TAG, "info size="+infos.size());

Comment: I saw your comment/edit made to my answer (reject by the commitee?). I am sorry that I don't quite understand your question there. I think my answer is clear enough that you cannot achieve that target unless you modify the AMS source code.